# SQLite always does a Full Table Scan when like used?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a text column containing URLs that are uniqe.

I need to do a SQL pattern match query, say using the 'like' SQL operator.

In such a scenario, will SQLite do a FTS ( Full Table Scan ) regardless of whether I have an index on that column or not ( column is a primary key )?

It seems to be that its doing a FTS as the speed of operation is telling - or is the speed impact due to the 'like' query although the column is indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)

> **4.0 The LIKE optimization**
>
> Terms that are composed of the LIKE or
>   GLOB operator can sometimes be used to
>   constrain indices. There are many
>   conditions on this use:
>
> 1. The left-hand side of the LIKE or GLOB operator must be the name of
>      an indexed column.
> 2. The right-hand side of the LIKE or GLOB must be a string literal that
>      does not begin with a wildcard
>      character.  [...]

**Update:** by default `case_sensitive_like` mode is OFF. Turning it ON might make it behave like `=`.

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = ON; -- OFF
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE field LIKE '...'
```

Comment: the left hadn side of like is the primary key and the right is a constant string followed sometimes by a wildcard.

As I said, most of the "pattern" strings are constants - like 'ftp:abs.com' - so there was no need to use like at all! Just for the sake of it, I wrote a one liner that calls a version of the query that uses '=' instead of 'like' when there are no wildcards, and it's wayyy faster - '=' takes 3 seconds on what takes 'like' 42 minutes! Is there no way to make 'like' call '=' if no wildcards are used?

Comment: .. I will have a look today and let you know.

Comment: no difference in timing at all - I need to share the databse - but the problem is that the values are extremely confidential - would sharing the schema and PERL code be enough?

Answer (score 4):

The LIKE operator will perform a full table scan if operand string begins with a wildcard character ("LIKE '%foo'"). It will use an index (if available) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If your `LIKE` uses a wildcard at the beginning of the match expression, such as `'%hris McCall'`, indexes will not be used.

Comment: Unfortunately, the wildcard '%' is used as a suffix - AFTER a constant text - something like 'FTP%'

What is amazing is that I just finished a little bit of data analysis and it looks like most of the "pattern" strings are constants - like 'ftp://abs.com' - so there was no need to use like at all!

Just for the sake of it, I wrote a one liner that calls a version of the query that uses '=' instead of 'like' when there are no wildcards, and it's wayyy faster - '=' takes 3 seconds on what takes  'like' 42 minutes!

Is there no way to make 'like' call '=' if no wildcards are used?

Comment: Why do you use SQLite for a project that has enough data to take 42 minutes? That must be hundreds of GB of data.

Comment: ... or maybe not hundreds, but probably tens.

Comment: No! This is for db that is ~12MB.

Note the difference in timings in using 'like' vs '='

Comment: 42 minutes on a 12MB database? This is a little hard to believe. Would you mind sharing the queries and table schema?

Comment: Things do not seem to be working out - I need to share the database - but the problem is that the values are extremely confidential - would sharing the schema and PERL code with embedded queries be enough?

Don't you need the complete 12MB db to do timings properly?